# Could not open Chrome browser rselenium in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, shinyapps, rselenium

I've been working on a Shiny app using `RSelenium`. Locally, everything works, but when I try to host it on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/), I encounter an error:

```
"Connecting to remote server"
Could not open chrome browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4567 after 0 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning: Error in checkError: Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
15: <Anonymous>
13: fn
8: retry
7: connect$retryingStartServer
6: eval
5: eval
4: eval
3: eval
2: eval.parent
1: local
```

**Shiny Code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(wdman)
library(shiny)
library(RSelenium)
library(httr)  
library(pagedown)
library(curl)
library(netstat)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
  textOutput("txt"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    cDrv <- find_chrome()
    eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
      args = c('--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280,800')
    ))
    client_server <- rsDriver(extraCapabilities = eCaps)

    remDr <- client_server$client
    remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
    remDr$maxWindowSize()
    title <- remDr$getTitle()
    output$txt <- renderText(as.character(title))
    remDr$quit()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**What I've Tried:**

- Checked dependencies locally, and everything is installed.
- Used the latest version of RSelenium.
- Set up appropriate configurations for the Chrome driver.

I'm open to any suggestions that could help me overcome this issue.